# How do I enable a function when my game is done doing an asynchronous function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

This has been fustrating me as a beginner/learning coder. I've been trying to make it so when my game finishes loading using an async method, it loads a button so you can continue. Instead, it ignores the function altogether, causing the button to still be there ingame and glitch out when you press it too early. I have my code right here; how can I fix this?

```
     IEnumerator LoadSceneAsynchronously(int levelIndex)
 {
     AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelIndex);
     while (!operation.isDone)
     {
         Debug.Log(operation.progress);
         loading.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("loading");
         text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle");
         yield return null;
     }
     if (!operation.isDone)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
         loading.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("loading disappear");
         text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("appear text");
         text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("blink text")
         yield return null;
     }
 }

 public void DestroyLoading()
 {
     gameObject.SetActive(false);
     GameIsDoneLoading = true;
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !GameIsDoneLoading == true)
     {
         Debug.Log("Space key was pressed.");
         text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("disappear text");
         logo.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("fpsa logo disappear");
     }
 }
```

Comment: A bit unclear how exactly your methods are related ... also in the `LoadSceneAsynchronously` after the `while` loop with condition `!l!operation.isDone` is finished how should be the `if(!operation.isDone)` ever get triggered? It is reached in the moment where `operation.isDone == true` to the inner block will never get executed

Comment: Also have in mind that if you load another scene (async or not) it means that the current scene is unloaded (since you don't use additive loading mode) => this Coroutine might get interrupted the moment its executing object is unloaded / destroyed

Comment: Ah. I'll try modify the code to what you've told me, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

When you 'yield' in a Coroutine, code execution returns to the exact same place in the next frame, so in the while loop above it just checks that condition every frame, then yields to the next frame. I believe what you want to do is...

```
IEnumerator LoadSceneAsynchronously(int levelIndex)
{
 // start the async loading
 AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelIndex);

// start playback of your animations in the scene
loading.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("loading");
text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle");
 
// now wait for the scene to fully load
while (!operation.isDone)
{
     Debug.Log(operation.progress);
     yield return null;
     // after yielding, we return here and repeat the while
     // loop on the next frame
}

// we have broken free of the while loop so the level has now fully loaded
// and operation.isDone is now true
// play some other animations to fade out the loading system?
     loading.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("loading disappear");
     text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("appear text");
     text.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("blink text")

// I'm assuming these animations take about 5 seconds to complete?
// so just wait in here for 5
yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

// loading level and animations all done...proceed to games
 DestroyLoading();
 }
```